# Forwarding SNMP ports over SSH

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, snmp, tunneling, socat

I access my work network through a VPN and have access to every host in there through SSH. Currently I need to access around 3000 hosts via SNMP, but corporate sec policies restrict SNMP access through VPN, and can't make an exception due to technical difficulties.

Googling around I found a couple of options, such as ssh tunneling or forwarding traffic with socat (http://www.morch.com/2011/07/05/forwarding-snmp-ports-over-ssh-using-socat/), but those options are point-to-point and I need to set them up for each of 3000 hosts I have to access.

Is there something I can do to access all hosts via SNMP with a single configuration? I have root access to a linux box inside the network with full SNMP access, perhaps I can setup something there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSH as a SOCKS4/5 proxy. Use a command like

```
ssh -D 8888 insidethevpn.example.com
```

Then configure your local workstation to use a SOCKS proxy ([mac](http://kb.k12usa.com/Knowledgebase/Proxy-Settings-on-a-Mac-OS-X), [windows](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/675-how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-windows-7/), [linux](http://linux.die.net/man/1/socksify)) with hostname `localhost` and port `8888`. Your computer should now route all your network traffic through the SSH connection.

Comment: [linux instructions](http://linux.die.net/man/1/socksify) (doing this in a comment since I don't have enough Rep to put it in the main answer)